# TCP sampler in JMeter reading exception (ERROR - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0)

Tags: tcp, thread-exceptions

-

### Step 1:

I have configured TCP sampler in Jmeter.

- ### Step 2:

  In TCP sampler I configured the following fields:
      1. Server Name (or) IP
      2. Port
      3. Check : Reuse-Connection,Close Connection,Set No-Delay 
      4. End Of Line (EOL) byte value (I set it to 13)
      5. Text to send ( I have given required message in this box)
  -

### Step 3:

I just click on Start(Green color) button.

Problem is here in the following step:

- ### Step 4:

  Jmeter is not stopping automatically.After waiting long time also.
  -

### ![Step 5:][1]

If I click on STOP button then only test is terminating and displaying error message in Log Viewer window like the following way :
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler:  org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0

Please help me what is the problem in my TCP sampler configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue.

The above exception will be raised when not giving sufficient time to read the message or when stopping Jmeter forcefully by clicking on the stop button.

To avoid this error in Jmeter Tcp sampler configuration, under timeout milliseconds section in connection field - insert some time, for example: 10000.